# Differences in Pearson skewness coefficients

Tags: r, skewness

I downloaded [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17zLx6EUh4v02fD38Qx-goTrCx5J0u5im/view) and [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OF-izDLC8Ny9b9SLi3XdkWixiqegoZWS/view) file. Then, I created histograms showing the daily cost and annual expenses per country. We observe that the histogram of cost21 is more symmetrical than the histogram of food21.

[image]

[image]

This is further confirmed by the Pearson skewness coefficients I calculated (`pearsonII`), which yield values of 0.4683039 and 0.5745134, respectively. However, if I use the `moments` package, I get exactly the opposite results, with values of 0.9714933 and 0.5786727, respectively.

Why is this happening? Which skewness coefficient values should I accept?

This is my code:

```
cost2021 <- costHealthyDiet[costHealthyDiet$Year == 2021, ]
cost21 <- cost2021$`Cost of a healthy diet`
food2021 <- foodExpenditureYear[foodExpenditureYear$Year == 2021, ]
food21 <- food2021$`Total food expenditure`
hist(cost21)
hist(food21)
pearsonII <- function(v){
  3*(mean(v)-median(v))/sd(v)
}
pearsonII(cost21)
pearsonII(food21)
install.packages("moments")
library(moments)
skewness(cost21)
skewness(food21
```

Comment: Different measures of skewness can give different results. This shouldn't be a surprise. The moment-based measure is a little more sensitive to one slight outlier.  (mean $-$ median) / SD is bounded by $[-1, 1]$ and multiplying it by 3 has the effect you would guess. Moment-based skewness is bounded but not so sharply.

Comment: @NickCox , I'm sorry. I fixed it!

Comment: I understand that they have a difference in estimating the skewness intensity. However, is it possible for them to provide opposite results? In any case, I comprehend that the coefficient from `moments` is not as reliable as the other one.

Comment: Like Nick Cox, I can't access your files. You can check the package code here to see how they compute the skewness coefficient (lines 8 and 9): https://github.com/cran/moments/blob/master/R/skewness.R

Comment: @J-J-J , I modified the file permissions. I believe they are accessible now.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to get contradictory results. Try 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4 where the mean equals the median and so one measure is zero immediately.

Comment: @NickCox , I understand! Thank you very much!

Comment: Skewness is not really something that you can capture by a single quantity. There are many different measures of skewness - dozens - which measure distinct, albeit usually broadly similar, things. Generally speaking\*, any pair of them can sometimes give opposite indications, one positive, the other negative.  $\:$ \* aside from a few pairs of measures that are  strictly proportional (or perhaps strictly monotonically related with the same 0-point). Multiple posts on site discuss this issue of different measures disagreeing.

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96684/919 describes a powerful way to assess skewness, using techniques of Exploratory Data Analysis (developed by John Tukey).  They go well beyond using a single number to characterize skewness.

Comment: @whuber , very interesting! Thank you very much for the reference!