# Reference about the Bowley’s coefficient of skewness

Tags: references, skewness

**Introduction.** In a test, I would like to use both the Fisher's moment coefficient of skewness ([Joanes, 1998](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9884.00122)) $g_{\text{Fisher}} = \frac{m_3}{{m_2}^{3/2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i - \overline{x})^{3}}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i - \overline{x})^{2} \right)^{3/2}}$
and the Bowley’s coefficient of skewness ([Ekström & Jammalamadaka, 2012](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016771521200154X?via%3Dihub)),
$g_{\text{Bowley}}=\frac{Q_{0.75} + Q_{0.25} - 2 \times Q_{0.5}}{Q_{0.75} - Q_{0.25}}$ (which is bounded $[-1,1]$).

**Question.**  I found that the rule of thumb to understand the outcome of
the Fisher's moment coefficient of skewness is the following ([Normality Testing - Skewness and Kurtosis](https://community.gooddata.com/metrics-and-maql-kb-articles-43/normality-testing-skewness-and-kurtosis-241), likely coming from [Bulmer, 1979, Principles of Statistics, Chapter 4 Descriptive properties of distributions, on Page 63](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Principles_of_Statistics.html?id=dh24EaSrmBkC&redir_esc=y)):

- If skewness is less than -1 or greater than 1, the distribution is highly skewed.
- If skewness is between -1 and -0.5 or between 0.5 and 1, the distribution is moderately skewed.
- If skewness is between -0.5 and 0.5, the distribution is approximately symmetric.

However, I did not find any reference reporting such a rule of thumb for the Bowley’s coefficient of skewness (e.g. research on [Web of Science](https://www.webofscience.com/wos/woscc/basic-search), by using "Bowley" and "skewness" as key words). Do you know a reference about a rule of thumb for understanding the Bowley’s coefficient of skewness (similar to that one above mentioned for the Fisher's one)?

Comment: These bullet points aren't really a "rule of thumb:" they are merely suggestions of possible qualitative descriptions.  They are essentially meaningless in themselves, but if adopted uniformly within a community they might be used for rough communication.

Comment: Bowley's coefficient is one point on a (standardized version) of a plot used in EDA for assessing skewness, as discussed in Tukey's work and the work of the EDA/robust stats community in the 1970's and 1980's.  See my post on this topic at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96684/919, which illustrates one way (out of several related ways) to use this idea successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution on the Tukey's generalized approach.

Comment: It looks like an answer from https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/686/peter-flom disappeared (and my comment to his reply as well).. Why?

Comment: Sometimes people delete answers altogether, for various reasons including wishing to develop them further without accumulating comments based on preliminary versions.  When a person deletes their own post, all comments to that post are also deleted.  People with sufficient reputation can view deleted posts (and their comments).  Because your comment contains added information, I will copy its contents to a comment just below so you can access it.

Comment: "Thanks a lot @Peter Flom.. by following your comments, I found other references, but still referring to the Fisher's moment (or at least, it looks like they refer to the Fisher's moment).. 
In https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3591587/ I found:
(i) "West et al. (1996) proposed a reference of substantial departure from normality as an absolute skew value > 2" and (ii) "West et al. (1996) proposed a reference of substantial departure from normality as an absolute kurtosis (proper) value > 7"....but nothing relevant about the Bowley's coefficient..." -- Ommo

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.. I did not know this feature of stackoverflow (about the deletion of answers).. However, I think his reply was nice and I was doing further research before any acceptance

Comment: I would guess (but am not sure) that the deletion might have been a response to my comment that the answer concerned *Normality* rather than the skewness and symmetry you have asked about.

Comment: Ok, it might be - My question is indeed related to the (a)symmetry of a distribution.

Comment: What are you testing, what are you hoping to accomplish by using both statistics, and how is that related to interpreting these qualitative characterizations of Bowley's coefficient?

Comment: Just pure curiosity